# Blow up of simply connected isolated singularity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, resolution-of-singularities

Let $X \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be a simply connected complex variety with a unique isolated singularity at $x\in X$.

Let $\tilde{X}$ be the strict transform of $X$ under the blow-up $\mathrm{Bl}_x(\mathbb{C}^n)$. Is it true that $\tilde{X}$ is a simply connected topological space as well?

Comment: No that is not true.  That fails for a cone over a smooth plane cubic.